# Netty's ResourceLeakDetector + paranoid mode - Does it log 'every' leak?

Tags: netty

My team has been having some debate around whether or not you will *always* get a logged message for every failure to release a `ByteBuf`.  Most, understandably, think you will.  I have been the biggest doubter.  My confusion ultimately stems from [this line of code](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/ResourceLeakDetector.java#L305), which appears to only log the leak if the string, which is composed of stack trace information is unique.

I wrote this code which OOM'd, yet only yielded two 'LEAK' error messages (one from each thread).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(ResourceLeakDetector.Level.PARANOID);
    final int len = 10_000_000;

    final PooledByteBufAllocator bufAllocator = new PooledByteBufAllocator();

    final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                bufAllocator.buffer(512);
            }
        }
    };

    final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                bufAllocator.buffer(512);
            }
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

When I run this, I set -Xmx low enough that I get 2 ERROR messages in the log.

So..  Is there only one 'leak' in the code above?  If running in the leak detector in paranoid mode, will we get a logged error message for every `ByteBuf` leak?

Updated question:
My team and I have a disagreement on what's happening.  My fear is that we have 2 code paths that 'leak' resources, but 20M 'leaks' actually happen.  They think only 2 'leaks' happen because we only see 2 ERRORs in the log. Which of us is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only log once per leak... Paranoid just means that it will sample all allocations + all operations.

Comment: Thanks Norman!  Would you say I only  have 2 'leaks' above?  If so, what would you call the failure to call `ByteBuf#release` on the 20 million created ByteBufs?

Comment: The leak detector depends on the GC to detect leaks which means that if your program is not kong-running it will not report all of it. also we only log the same stack once.

Comment: Hey Norman, sorry if I'm wasting your time.  I added an updated question in the OP.  I _think_ you answered my question, but the team is still interpreting your responses differently.  If you answer that updated question, I should be able to mark this as answered and leave you alone:)

Comment: You are correct... there may be more then "two leaks" if they happen on exactly the same code path